# Dialog with custom theme centered programmatically?

Tags: android, dialog, customization

I have a dialog with a custom theme:

```
final Dialog d = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

This makes my dialog background transparent.

Now the problem is if I let the normal theme(style.dialog) it is centered in my screen but now it has no layout and is in the upper left corner of my screen. Is there a way to programmatically center the dialog?

Comment: Well, a solution I figured was that in my dialog.xml layout I set the main layout to fill parent and as a sublayout I put a my custom sized dialog. This is not probably the best way to do it, but it kinda worked out. Note:this is only doable via a custom layout dialog. Still no programmatically solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't actually find a programatic solution to my problem, instead in my customdialog.xml I put the main layout into a RelativeLayout with fill_parent for height/width and then put the layout atribute centerInParent="true".

Answer (score -3):

construct your dialog by extends Dialog,
override the style & content(by setContentView)